# Easiest way to REGEX Capture eveything except what you specify?

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds, negate

I for the life of me cannot figure out how to negate everything but what I want to capture with REGEX.

I get close with [^(\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}]

But doing a replace in powershell with an input of:
1234-567-899 ABC 1W(23W) BLUE BIKE30 KIT

I get: 1234-567-8991(2330

Instead of 1234-567-899

Comment: [^...] defines a negated class. None of the specified characters is matched - this is not you want, but rather probably a negative lookaround is required, but your question is ambiguous. What do you want to negate?

Comment: I think i found the answer, i wanted to negate everything but the numbers at the beginning. (?<=\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3})(.*$) seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regex `-replace` to remove everything except for the stuff you want to keep.

In your example

```
"1234-567-899 ABC 1W(23W) BLUE BIKE30 KIT" -replace '^([-\d]+).*', '$1'
```

would return `1234-567-899`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `(?:^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3})(.*)$`

Comment: Doesnt that take it out of the negated set? I want to REGEX everything following the group of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To match any text after `<4-DIGITS>-<3-DIGITS>-<3-DIGITS>` pattern at the start of the string, you may use

```
(?<=^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3}).*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D%29.*&i=1234-123-123Some%20text%20I%20need). Details:

- `(?<=^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{3})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\d{4}` - four digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d{3}-\d{3}` - three digits, `-`, three digits
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than newline chars, as many as possible